# Is it possible to install older catalyst versions through jockey?  

Tags: 11.10, ati, fglrx, jockey

Is it possible to install older catalyst versions through jockey?

There is a 100% CPU bug for OpenCL applications in ALL catalyst versions post 11.4.

I tried installing from ATI website using --build-pkg, but something isnt working, i dont know if its kernel 3 causing issues or what.

Guess im asking if anyone has rebuilt for 11.10, or just if there is a repo i can use to test myself?

Answer (score 1):

Using jokey, no, and older versions of drivers required different kernels / xorg configurations, so you will not be able to to so.

Comment: well it works on 11.04 so is there any chance someone might update it for use on 11.10? otherwise people like me are stuck on 11.04 until ATI fix the issue which i dont think they are going to.