# What would be the best video driver to use on my Dell Vostro 1000 running Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, video, ati, fglrx

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is my ATI graphics card supported in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74171/is-my-ati-graphics-card-supported-in-ubuntu)

I recently re installed Oneric on my Dell Vostro 1000.  I got the wireless working (which wasn't a big deal) and now I am working on the video config.  The video card is an ati x1150 Right now it seems to be using the gallium 3d driver version 0.3 i think and its working pretty well but I have noticed some sluggishness in the video.  I was looking through some other posts about the possibility of using fglrx on this system.

[Jockey not detecting my ATI IGP Xpress 1150](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49176/jockey-not-detecting-my-ati-igp-xpress-1150)

[Is it possible to install older catalyst versions through jockey?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78845/is-it-possible-to-install-older-catalyst-versions-through-jockey)

but it seems that its either not possible or not recommended so my question is this.  Would it be worth my time to try to install say catalyst 9.2 (i believe this is the last version to officially support my card) or should I stick with gallium?  If I should stick with the gallium then is there anywhere I can get an update to it that will (hopefully) fix some of the lag?  Would the x update or xorg edgers ppa have the update?  Thank you for taking the time to try and help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [supported hardware](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Hardware) table the ATI driver you should be using is already installed and used by default in Ubuntu 11.10.

Your card, the ATI X1150 uses the RS400 chipset, which according to the table, is supported by the catalyst legacy or open-source drivers.

Since the first cannot be installed in Ubuntu 11.10 unless you are able to install and use a kernel version 2.6.28 (or earlier) you are only able to use the second and that is already installed in your system.

Comment: Thats pretty much what I figured, so gallium it is.  I'll just have to look into updating it.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DesktopExperienceTeam/UnityHardwareRequirements) is a list of hardware requirements for running Unity 3D on your Ubuntu.

A self test for checking Unity 3D compatibility is provided by Ubuntu itself:

```
/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
```

If your hardware is not supported, you can fall back on the 2D desktop. Which is also great.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unity 3D runs fine and i have direct rendering its just a bit laggy at times, nothing I can't handle.  I just wanted to know if there was an alternative.  It seems as though the gallium driver that was installed by default is the best solution.